# How to set data into ChromeOptions to the Selenium Chrome driver using Java?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I try to inject into `ChromeOptions` flag `autoplay-policy` - `Document user activation is required` for block autoplay video for test performance.

I have several attempts. But no one didn't work.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = Maps.newHashMap();
prefs.put("--autoplay-policy", "Document user activation is required.");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Or

```
options.setCapability("--autoplay-policy", "Document user activation is required.");
```

I'm trying use URL `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy` for set `Document user activation` using pup-up menu. But when Selenium click by `RELAUNCH NOW` for apply my test crash. I need to inject it before start Chrome.

[image]

I'm looking for any opportunity to block auto-playing video when `chromedriver` start. Please help me resolve this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, imposible to block autoplay of videos via native option "autoplay-policy". Meanwhile it doesn't work, I start Chrome with the chrome plugin "Disable HTML5 Autoplay". I attach the code for manage this plugin from Selenium API:

```
public class PluginHTML5Autoplay extends PluginChrome {

    private final String fileName = "html5autoplay_0_6_2.crx";
    private static final String PageSetup = "chrome-extension://efdhoaajjjgckpbkoglidkeendpkolai/options.html";
    private static final String XPathSelect = "//select[@id='default-mode']";

    @Override
    public void addPluginToChrome(ChromeOptions options) throws Exception {
        super.addPluginToChrome(options, this.fileName);
    }

    public static void disableAutoplay(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get(PageSetup);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPathSelect))).selectByVisibleText("Disable autoplay");
    }

    public void disableNothing(WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get(PageSetup);
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(XPathSelect))).selectByVisibleText("Disable nothing");
    }
}
```

The default option when you start Chrome with this plugin is "Disable Autoplay". Thus, you only need to manage the plugin in case you whant to active autoplay.